# When NtUnmapViewOfSection is called?

Tags: windows, malware, sandbox

I'm analyzing an executable and I see that it created a process child and within it there was a call to NtUnmapViewOfSection. I know that this method is almost always malicious and can be used for process hollowing for example.

I want to know if there's a good reason to see this method called while analyzing an executable in sandbox (in my case Cuckoo Sandbox)? Or I can be sure that there was a malicious activity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would Windows have functions whose only use is malicious?

Comment: Nt and Zw APIs are native APIs. Although they aren't evil per se, they are usually used because they're the core API. They are like using a sniper rifle. to focus in on a function. They aren't natively used by programs that are honestly compiled. And are very poorly documented. This is why they are more or less inherently malicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NtUnmapViewOfSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567119(v=vs.85).aspx) (and the corresponding [NtMapViewOfSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481(v=vs.85).aspx)) are function calls used by Windows kernel-mode drivers to [manage shared memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563684(v=vs.85).aspx).  These functions can be used to share memory between kernel space and user space: for example, a driver could use them to communicate with a user-space configuration tool.